# Getting PTS from MPEG-4?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-4, pts

I'm trying to get the PTS value from a MPEG-4 video that I'm streaming using RTP without using Transport Stream (TS). I've been able to get this value when muxing the video in TS, but now I want to send the video without using the TS and I wonder where to locate the PTS...

Is there any header that indicates where the PTS is stored or something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

PTS values are stamped only in PES header which is part of MPEG2 systems standard - this is only applicable in the Transport stream.

PTS values can be available in MP4 file as well. MP4 files are structured in various atoms hierarchies.

The PTS values are available in CTTS atom - which can be browsed under the following hierarchy.  **`moov->track->mdia->minf->stbl->ctts`** .